# How can I remove or hide Disk Utility software from my computer?

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I want to remove Disk Utility from my Ubuntu computer. How can I remove it?

For security reasons, I want to hide that utility from others. How can I hide it, then unhide it again?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @Pilot6 for security. and I want to hide that utility from others.

Comment: @MadhavNikam what are your requirements  ? As it has been already mentioned, removing this utility, will remove the desktop. If we're talking about changing permissions on who can run the utility, sudo user can still change them. Are your users sudo or non sudo ? Please give us more info.

Comment: @Serg I edit question.. I got some very good answers and info.. I make broad my question.

Comment: I am so happy both answers are very usefull and perfect for my reqirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other users do not have sudo priviliges, `sudo chmod 700 $(which gnome-disks) && sudo mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop.bak` are sufficient

This line of commands changes permissions to only available to root and hides application from appearing in the search launcher. To undo everything, run `sudo sh -c  'chmod 755 /usr/bin/gnome-disks && mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop.bak /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop`

Hiding any file in linux can also be done my adding a leading dot to filename, like so: `sudo mv /usr/bin/gnome-disks /usr/bin/.gnome-disks`. You can do the same with the `.desktop` file. Undoing the effects is merely using mv command with the addresses swapped

Comment: If they can find `gnome-disks`, they will find it either way. But it is very unlikely.

Comment: @Serg Undo command not work.. and terminal shows > > no error nothing do anything.

Comment: @MadhavNikam ah, so the $(which gnome-disks) wont work if you've changed the permissions. You'd have to give full path. I'll edit my answer in a second

Comment: @Serg sudo sh -c  'chmod 755 /usr/bin/gnome-disks && mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop.bak /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop this not produce output? >

Comment: @MAdhavNikam yes, this operation does not show anything in console.  If you have done the first command `sudo chmod 700 $(which gnome-disks) && sudo mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop.bak` This hides the disk utility from others, except root user. After you run ` sudo sh -c 'chmod 755 /usr/bin/gnome-disks && mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop.bak /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop ` this should be quiet, but gnome-disks should now be available again.

Comment: yes! I test your answers with Pilot6 and A.B. answers. no way to display it again. disks utility can again available if and only if it reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove gnome-disk-utility form Ubuntu without removing desktop environment.

This utility requires sudo password to perform any dangerous tasks.

You can hide it by removing .desktop shortcut from `/usr/share/applications`

The correct way to prevent users from dangerous actions is not to give them administrative rights. You can create an ordinary user by

System Settings -> Users & Groups

and let people you do not trust login only with that account.

There is also a workaround, but this is a bad practice.

```
sudo mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop.bak
```

This will remove shortcut from unity panel and programs menu.

To revert it back run

```
sudo mv /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop.bak /usr/share/applications/gnome-disks.desktop
```

Comment: And any user can start it via the command line. Nice answer.

Comment: sudo user will always be able to start it. But the question was how to hide it from people who do not probably know how to use command prompt.

Comment: And the removal isn't a problem. The desktop package is a meta package

Comment: It still ain't the complete answer, though.

Comment: There is no way to prevent sudo user from spoiling disks or starting any apps. The only way is not to give sudo permissions to everyone.

Comment: @Pilot6 Can you plz explain in details.

Comment: @Pilot6 I suggest instead of rm do mv , gnome-disks.desktop to gnome-disks.desktop.bak

Comment: @serg Good catch!

Comment: @Pilot6 waw!!! and add also how to display it.

Comment: But if do not make a backup, the package can always be reinstalled. And the .desktop will be restored.

Comment: The `mv` command moves the file from the first specifed location to the second (in the case the file that makes the thing appear in the menu), a version using `rm` removes the specified files. You can restrict sudo user to certain commands (using command aliases so the user can only do some things). Also, everyone note there are loads of disk utilities, like gparted, parted, `fdisk`... all require sudo permission though

Answer (score 1):

*This program can be easily removed. The desktop environment is **NOT** removed.*

---

`Disks` or better `/usr/bin/gnome-disks` is part of the package `gnome-disk-utility`.

```
% which gnome-disks 
/usr/bin/gnome-disks
% apt-file search /usr/bin/gnome-disks
gnome-disk-utility: /usr/bin/gnome-disks
```

Therefore

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-disk-utility
```

If you need the tool again:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

---

*Explanations:*

Here is the output of the remove command:

```
% sudo apt-get remove gnome-disk-utility
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-disk-utility ubuntu-gnome-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 6.619 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

`ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and all other `*-desktop` are only meta packages. These can be removed without problems.:

```
% apt-cache rdepends gnome-disk-utility
gnome-disk-utility
Reverse Depends:
  gnome-disk-utility:i386
  gnome-disk-utility:i386
  gnome-disk-utility:i386
  ubuntukylin-desktop
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  lubuntu-desktop
  gnome-core
  ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: This will remove ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: @Pilot6  And anyway, `gnome-desktop` is a meta package.

Comment: @A.B. Littele curiocity in mind... can it applicable for other utility also?

Comment: @MadhavNikam That depends on what programs you mean. The procedure should not be generalized.

Comment: @Wilf It is to complicated and still dangerous on updates.

Comment: @Pilot6 that's not true.

Comment: Tested this answer. Works. Ubuntu deskto still intact. Good answer AB ! Upvoted

Comment: @Serg As I said =)

Comment: @Pilot6 I've tested this answer just now. Everything still intact, works perfectly